# How do I find the maximum value of a column and the other information of the other columns from the same raw in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with three column, two of which are `character` and the third is `numeric`. How do I find the maximum value of the numerical column while getting all the rest of the information from the row?

so far I have:

```
apply(dataframe, 2, max)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `which.max` to get the numeric index of the third column, subset the rows by using that as row index.

```
df[which.max(df[,3]),]
```

If there are ties, we can compare (`==`) the elements of the third column with the `max` value of that column to give a logical index which can as well be used as the row index.

```
df[df[,3]==max(df[,3]),]
```